# Picasso: Why bitmap are not loaded in my Adapter

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

My ImageView will load the image if I am not using Picasso and use only BitmapFactory.decodeFile. When changing it to use Picasso, the image doesn't show up. Even if I put Callback to see whether it hit the success and failure but none of them hit.

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View layout = convertView;
        ImageView imageView;

        var page = (BasePage)Pages [position];

        if (layout == null) {
            layout = LayoutInflater.From (Context).Inflate (Resource.Layout.view_page_thumbnail, null);
            imageView = layout.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imgThumbnail);
        } else {
            imageView = layout.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imgThumbnail);
            var bmpDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.Drawable;

            if (bmpDrawable != null && bmpDrawable.Bitmap != null) {
                bmpDrawable.Bitmap.Recycle ();
                bmpDrawable.Bitmap.Dispose ();
                bmpDrawable.Dispose();
                bmpDrawable = null;
            }
        }

        imageView.SetImageBitmap (null);


            Picasso.With (Application.Context)
                .Load (Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file://" + page.FileLocation))
            .CenterInside ()
            .Fit ()
                .Into (imageView, ()=>{
                    var a = 0;
                    var b= 0;
                },
                    ()=>{
                        var c=0;
                        var d=0;
                    }
                ); 

        imageView.Tag = page.FileLocation;
        layout.Tag = "Image" + position;

        return layout;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
.Load (Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file://" + page.FileLocation))
```

With the following code:

```
.Load (new File(page.FileLocation))
```

Comment: Maybe no width and height on LayoutParameter assigned but I thought I have given it in layout resource file which I have used on BitmapFactory.DecodeFile version.

Comment: Can you share your xml file please  ?(where the `ImageView` tag is defined)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
picass.with(Context).load(url).into(ImageView).
```